# MongoDB not working after authorization

Tags: mongodb, digital-ocean

Can't find answer anywhere. This is the problem:
I set it up on digitalocean my NodeJS project with MongoDB. I've installed NodeJS and MongoDB, and also cloned my project. At first I run my project on port 8888 and it worked fine with mongodb. Then I added `admin` user to the `admin` table and whenever I again run my nodejs project I get this error

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: not authorized on test to execute command`

How to authorize then ? Should I somehow authorize before running my app ?

The user that I've created:

```
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "******",
    pwd: "****",
    roles: [ { role: "root", db: "admin" } ]
  }
)
```

Comment: How are you authenticating from your app (how are you passing user name and password)? This is rather important. Please edit your question to show this (without your real credentials of course).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change mongodb connection string with user authentication to avoid this issue. if your created use "admin_user" and password "test1234" and mongodb server "127.0.0.1:27017" then connection string looks like below,

```html
"MONGODB_URL": "mongodb://admin_user:test1234@127.0.0.1:27017/YourDBName",
```

Comment: Yeah... this was the case... I've solve that after 20 min after I posted the question. First I setup DB in digitalocean, but now I set it up on mlab.com and works good. :)